# Delete a file from specific directory Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have some files in "public/uploads/somephoto.jpg". How to delete this file? I tried

```
unlink(url('/uploads/somefile.jpg'));
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Is the actual code you tried to run?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but the structure of the code was the same and the answer below helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if file in your `public folder` then

```php
unlink(public_path('uploads/somefile.jpg'));
```

or if it is stored in `storage folder` then

```php
unlink(storage_path('uploads/somefile.jpg'));
```

- here  `url()` retrun `http` url but for delete file edit file you need system path which will be get by `storage_path()` or `public_path()`

Comment: you know that these path helpers take a path as an argument? `storage_path('uploads/somefile.jpg')`

Comment: ohh @lagbox thaank you for info